# How to get profile data from various social media plateforms

Tags: node.js, reactjs, facebook-graph-api, youtube-data-api, instagram-graph-api

My requirement is to search profile data based on some parameters from various social media plateforms like instagram, facebook, youtube, twitter.

How to get  no of posts, followers, profile links, following and many more of any user profile from instagram, facebook, twitter

I have tried instagram api, facebook graph api for getting profile details.

https://www.instagram.com/developer/
https://developers.facebook.com/

They all are asking for login and access token.
How can i get profile details without login.

Comment: You forgot your question.

Comment: Please read [how to ask]

Comment: @DhananjaySharma please read **[ask]** and [edit] your question.

Comment: Please go read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). and stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic..

Comment: If API's are designed to require a login and access token it's probably best to follow their documentation. Hacking around the documented API will likely leave you with a broken solution if/when things change.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understood your question, but I'm gonna assume that you're looking for YouTube and Instagram's APIs to get the information you mentioned.

You can find [YouTube API here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3).

I'm not sure if Instagram will let you get that information tho, check it out [here](https://www.instagram.com/developer/).

Hope my answer was what you're looking for.